# Is there a way to have more fine-grain control over the text colors of dart in IntelliJ/Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, dart, intellij-idea

For instance, in the example below, I would like to have a different color for the annotations in Dart (`@deprecated`), but I can only do so, if I change the color of the "Top level getter reference".

[image]

Another thing I would like to change is the color of class names in their declaration (`class A`) and their usage (`A(23, isB: false)`).

Is there anyway to do this, like a plugin or something? Feel free to tell me if this isn't really a fit and that I should remove this.